# Read quoted values in txt file with data.table::fread()

Tags: r, data.table

I have a simple txt file: (values are in quotes and separated by tabs)

```
"Col1" "Col2" "Col3"  
"A" "1,1" "C"  
"B" "2,1" "C"  
"C" "3,1" "C"
```

I would like to read the file using `fread()`. Since the middle column should be numeric, I use `dec = ","`.

However, the command:

`fread("myFile.txt", sep = "\t", dec = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

fails to read Col2 as numeric. Specifying `colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "character")` does not make any difference.

Is there a way to accurately read the file using `fread()` (without post-processing)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you also try `fread("myFile.txt", sep = "\t", dec = ",", colClasses = "character")`? (you will need post-processing then though)

Comment: Hi Jaap, many thanks both for the edit and your reply. I just tried it, with no success. What difference would that make? The desired data.table should have read the middle column as numeric.

Comment: *"The desired data.table should have read the middle column as numeric"* -- not necessarily. Enclosing numeric values in doubles quotes like this seems pretty unusual, so it shouldn't be *that* surprising that `fread` and `read.table` both fail to parse this field as `numeric`. File readers are generally implemented to handle a certain range of standard formats, not *every* possible format.

Comment: So, a possible answer is "What you ask for is NOT supported by data.table because it is quite unusual?" (maybe not the answer I am hoping for, but still, good to know!)

Comment: It seems that way; but that's not such a bad thing -- whatever extra code required to handle this very uncommon case would add at least some unnecessary overhead to reading the other 99.9999% of files that are formatted in a standard way. If this file is being generated by some other process or program, you might consider looking into fixing it on that end. Otherwise just do the `Col2 := as.numeric(Col2)`, etc. conversion afterwards, which should be pretty fast, especially compared to the time it takes to read a file from disk.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Please post it, so I can accept it as the correct answer. Unfortunately, I have minimal control on the actual file. I sidestepped the problem by manually changing all "," to "." and then coercing to numeric. It still feels bad to have to treat a single file in a different way though (somehow the other files are ok)

Comment: I believe this is identical to this outstanding issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2052

Comment: @MichaelChirico At the beginning I thought so, too, but now I am not so sure. It is explictly stated in the documentation that coercion only happens to higher classes (I think this means that you can say that a numeric is a character, but not the other way around). I am quite sure the failure to coerce ti numeric has everything to do with the quotes and nothing to do with the fact that the decimal point is wrong. You can see that if you change the commas to dots in the txt file, you will see that the problem persists.

Comment: yes, IIUC that's what the issue's about -- automatically detecting numeric even if it's wrapped in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to backtrack a little bit on my previous comments; it looks like `read.table` does handle this situation successfully.

Demonstrating with the following object,

```
df <- data.frame(
    Col1 = LETTERS[1:3], 
    Col2 = sub(".", ",", 1:3 + 0.1, fixed = TRUE), 
    Col3 = rep("C", 3), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

which looks like this on disk:

```
write.table(
    df,
    sep = "\t", 
    row.names = FALSE
)
# "Col1"    "Col2"  "Col3"
# "A"   "1,1"   "C"
# "B"   "2,1"   "C"
# "C"   "3,1"   "C"
```

Writing this to a temporary file,

```
tf <- tempfile()
write.table(
    df,
    file = tf,
    sep = "\t", 
    row.names = FALSE
)
```

`read.table` will process the second column as `numeric` when the proper arguments are provided:

```
str(read.table(tf, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ","))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Col1: chr  "A" "B" "C"
#  $ Col2: num  1.1 2.1 3.1
#  $ Col3: chr  "C" "C" "C"
```

More conveniently, `read.delim2` may be used also:

```
str(read.delim2(tf, header = TRUE))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Col1: chr  "A" "B" "C"
#  $ Col2: num  1.1 2.1 3.1
#  $ Col3: chr  "C" "C" "C"
```

I can't really say why `fread` does not handle this, but if it is a sufficiently common scenario the package maintainers may want to account for it. You might consider opening an issue ticket on the GitHub repository and inquiring about this.

Comment: So `fread()` can't read it correctly, but `read.table()` and `read.delim2()` can. Unfortunately, both methods do not return a data.table (I am not sure just how bad this is for very large files). It seems that we could use a clarification from the `data.table` team if this behavior is intentional or accidental. I will shortly post my own answer with a relatively simple (but much slower) way to handle this issue after reading the file.